# Why mongoose connection execute after port listening

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

If i made connection of mongoose before port listening, console of port listening come first then it execute connection console statement, Why ?

Because i want to know, why is it happening ?

Comment: We can't really explain why the code is behaving that way without seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your code to the question as well, so others can check for the bug.

However, I will try to answer anyway. Mongoose connection is asynchronous, so you need to wait for it to finish. That means, you should build your server after receiving the successful connection to the database.

If your previous code was something like this:

```js
mongoose.connect(config.db);

const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

You should refactor it like this:

```js
mongoose.connect(config.db).then(() => {

  // Wait for MongoDB connection first, and then build the server
  const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${server.address().port}`);
  });

});
```